# mockito return sequence of objects on spy method

Tags: java, mockito

I know you can set several different objects to be be returned on a mock. Ex.

```
when(someObject.getObject()).thenReturn(object1,object2,object3);
```

Can you do the same thing with a spied object somehow? I tried the above on a spy with no luck. I read in the docs to use `doReturn()` on a spy like below

```
doReturn("foo").when(spy).get(0);
```

But `deReturn()` only accepts one parameter. I'd like to return different objects in a specific order on a spy. Is this possible?

I have a class like the following and i'm trying to test it. I want to test `myClass`, not `anotherClass`

```
public class myClass{

    //class code that needs several instances of `anotherClass`

    public anotherClass getObject(){
        return new anotherClass();
    }
}
```

Answer (score 50, accepted):

You can chain `doReturn()` calls before `when()`, so this works (mockito 1.9.5):

```
private static class Meh
{
    public String meh() { return "meh"; }
}

@Test
public void testMeh()
{
    final Meh meh = spy(new Meh());

    doReturn("foo").doReturn("bar").doCallRealMethod().when(meh).meh();

    assertEquals("foo", meh.meh());
    assertEquals("bar", meh.meh());
    assertEquals("meh", meh.meh());
}
```

Also, I didn't know you could do `when(x.y()).thenReturn(z1,z2)`, when I have to do this I use chained `.thenReturn()` calls as well:

```
when(x.y()).thenReturn(z1).thenThrow().thenReturn(z2)
```

Comment: I'll just add that I would prefer the `BDDMockito` aliases, but it's a matter of preference in the code. That would give the following : `willReturn("foo").willReturn("bar").willCallRealMethod().given(meh).meh();`